# Aggregating all relations into one table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, erd

I'm trying to design an enterprise level database architecture. In ERD level I have an Issue.

Many of my tables have relations which each other. there may be some developments in the future and my design should be flexible and also fast on gathering the results.

In recent days I have created a Parent Table which is named **Node** and all of my Functional Tables has an one-to-one relation with this table. 
(Functional Tables are those who keep real life datas like Content, User, Folder, Role, .... and not those who related to applications life-cycle) 
So before adding a record to each table, We must add a Node into the **Node** Table and take the new NodeId to add into secondary table.

**Node** table alone, has a Many-To-Many relation with itself. so I designed this table to keep whole of my relation concerns.

[image]

All of the other entities are like the **User** and are related to the Node table as shown above.

Problem is: Does this design makes my relational queries faster on **NodeAssoc** table or It's better to keep relations separately ?

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> There may be some developments in the future and my design should be flexible and also fast on gathering the results.

Flexibility and performance are two separate things.  Which have different ways to approach them or solve them. When you are designing a database, you have to concider database principles. Normalization is very important to keep in mind. Relations one-to-one and many-to-many are by design not common. In your case you are mentioning one-to-one and many-to-many relations, on which I have my worries.

- Advice one -> Denormalize (merge) one-to-one tables to one table.
  This reduces the amount of joins.
- Advice two -> Introduce a bridge table on many-to-many table,
  because there could be multiple matches. Fixing multiple matches means
  complex queries, which leads to performance drop.
- Advice three -> Use proper indexes in order to improve the performance

Increasing of flexibility can be through using Database Views, which is a query. The structure of the database may change in the future, while modifieing the view can be very fast too.

Comment: I have inspired this design from AlfrescoECM ERD. and this application makes use of something like it. I have Insertion Overhead actually but I could also add a lots of different relation on The newly added entity. So main Question is about Aggregation. I want to see if aggregation makes my queries faster (Because of high number of queries on NodeAssoc table) or it's better to keep tables Normalized (By adding a lots of Extra tables.

Comment: You can aggregate and insert, this will reduce the amount of data in your table. Reducing data will increase the total amount of time getting results. But aggregating data means also, losing details/insight.

Comment: A common solution is like invoices. You have an invoice header and an invoice line. The header contains aggregated data, the invloice line has the details. This way you have them both.